# Does the following program contain a dangling reference?

Tags: c++, reference, dangling-pointer

I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using int_arr = int[3];

int& f(int_arr& arr, int index)
{
    return arr[index];
}

int main() {
    int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int& g = f(arr, 0);
    g = 5;

    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Is `arr[index]` returned by f considered a dangling reference?

I don't think this is a dangling reference since the `arr` object continues to exist even after `f` returns (so the reference is valid), but I wanted to confirm my understanding. I compiled this with `-fsanitize=undefined` and it compiled fine and produced the expected output.

Comment: No `g` references a member of the array `arr` (in the scope of `main`) which has the same lifetime.  ( It would probably be better, for the sake of the question, if you called the local and the parameter by a different name. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `arr` and `g` have the same life time, so there's no dangling reference.

Note however that you *can* easily create a dangling reference with your function:

```
int empty;
int& ref = empty;

int &f(int arr[], int idx) { return arr[idx]; }
void g()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    ref = f(arr, 0);
}

int main()
{
    g();
    // ref is accesable here and complete garbage
}
```

Comment: I don't think your example correctly shows a dangling reference. You can't rebind a reference so the assignment inside `g()` just changes the value of the `int` "empty".